# Solving $\sum_r \frac {\mathrm B_{z_r}(a+m_r+1,b)}{\mathrm B_{z_r}(a+m_r,b)}=K$ for $a$ and $b$

Tags: numerical-analysis, nonlinear-equations

How to numerically find the solution for $a$ and $b$ of this equation

$$\sum_r \frac {\mathrm B_{z_r}(a+m_r+1,b)}{\mathrm B_{z_r}(a+m_r,b)}=K$$
where $m_r$ are non-negative integers, $0<K<1$, $0<a$, $0<b$, and $\mathrm B_{z}(a,b)=\int_0^zx^{a-1}(1-x)^{b-1}dx$ is the incomplete beta function

Comment: Anything known about zr ? Because it looks a lot harder when z isn't a constant.

Comment: @MSalters $0<z_r<1$ is a real constant, and can be different for each $r$

Answer (score 3):

If you have any sort of guess, you can use the following representation:
$$ g(a,b) = \sum_r \frac{B_{z_r}(a+m_r + 1,b)}{B_{z_r}(a+m_r,b)} - K$$
Which should be $g(a^*,b^*)=0$ when you find the best solution,$(a^*,b^*)$. You can then use a method like [Newton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method)'s for solving nonlinear equations.

If you have no clue what initial guess to make for the $(a,b)$ pair, you could formulate the problem as an optimization problem with the cost function:
$$ J = \frac{1}{2} g(a,b)^2 $$

With this cost function, you could technically try any optimization approach, though I would recommend some approach that can try to find a global minimum. Some examples might be using [Genetic Algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm) or Global/Local [Particle Swarms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_swarm_optimization) to find the global minimum.

Comment: There is probably not a unique solution. The equation $g(a,b)=0$ will define $a$ as a function of $b$ implicitly, over a certain domain.

Comment: @becko Why do you suspect there is no unique solution?

Comment: You have two variables $(a,b)$ and a single equation. Over a range of values of $K$, there have to be more than one solution.

Comment: @becko Oh right!

Comment: Two variables one restriction, I guess there should be a generic solution of the form b=f(a). From particular data trials, plots yields a line for f(a) at least for the ranges of a, b visualized.

Comment: I can be happy with a first order approximation to f(a)

Comment: @becko For this case, couldn't one assume parametric forms like $a = a(s) =\sum a_i \phi_i (s)$ & $b= b(s) = \sum b_i \phi_i (s)$ for some basis ${\phi_i}$ and in turn solve for the coefficients ${b_i}$ & ${a_i}$ to find an approximate path of solutions? You may have to solve a harder optimization problem, but it could pay off. Though actually, this might become some sort of calculus of variation problem, so maybe not..

Comment: I suppose the easiness of the calculation will depend on your cleverness in choosing the basis functions $\phi_i (s)$. I have no idea what would be a good choice. Also, expanding in a set of basis functions is usually useful when you manage to get a linear system of equations (maybe infinite)... But in this case the $a$'s and $b$'s are inside Beta functions, which makes it much harder :(

Comment: @becko Oh yeah, you'd still be solving a nonlinear equation for the coefficients! I view this reformulation of finding an optimum path the same as solving a calculus of variations problem using the the Rayleigh-Ritz method. Not easy to do, but it can surely be done in finite time.